# Specifications of the Git Algorithm

Tags: git, algorithm, version-control, versioning, specifications

What are the specifications of the Git Algorithm?

I researched a lot, but i only find informations about a specif algorithm (like the diff algorithm).

But i would líke to know more about the general Algoroithm. f.e. that the Algorithm allows you to work with binary data. What are more specifications?

thanks.

Why does Git support binary data and cvs not? What are the benefits?

Comment: [You can just take a peak](https://github.com/git/git).

Comment: You can check the detail work flow for git in git book, as the part Recording Changes to the Repository ( https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).

Answer (score 0):

Check here:
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/

The ones that end with "-format" are usually about binary data formats.

Also this book Chapter 10:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects